# SQL : how to select the last inserted record from a table joined to another

Tags: mysql, sql

> -Fields of table "news" :  `id,title,category`
>
> note: the field "category" is a foreign key related to table category
>
> -Fields of table "category" :  `id,title`

I need to join "news" with "category" and get the **last inserted news** of each category

example:

table news

```
id-----title-----category  
1-----title1-----3  
2-----title2-----3  
3-----title3-----5  
4-----title4-----5
```

table category

```
id-----title  
3------cat3  
5------cat5
```

result should be:

```
id-----title-----category  
2-----title2-----cat3  
4-----title4-----cat5
```

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt!

Comment: Add a date column containing the insert date .

Comment: sagi, no need for date column,,i can get the last inserted record using the primary key id

Comment: jarlh, post updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume that the id will always increment with a new item then this query should be safe. That then relies upon the field to perform a function for which it was not intended, and if there was an `insert_date` field that would probably be superior.

```
Select news.id, news.title, category.title as category
  From news
  Inner Join (Select Max(id) as id From news Group By category) As latest 
     On latest.id = news.id
  Inner Join category On news.category = category.id;
```

Comment: this query gave me the following : Unknown column 'latest.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Sorry, typo. Please try again.

Comment: Good news! To help with the presentation of questions and answers on this site please mark the answer as Accepted if it fulfils your requirements.

Comment: Mendosi, what about if I also want to get the category title ?

Comment: Yes, I missed that bit in your question. Please see updated answer.